# How do I get Data value from Combine + Alamofire Error response?

Tags: swift5, decoding, combine, openapi-generator

Below is my code to call api and it returns Swift.Error when the api call has error.

```
AccountAPI.postAccount(withSignUpCommand: signUpCommand)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] result in
                guard let self = self else { return }

                switch result {
                    case .finished:
                        self.logger.debug("signUp completed.")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self.isAuthenticating = false
                        self.logger.error("signUp error : \(error)")
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] (statusCode, userId) in
                guard let self = self else { return }

                self.logger.debug("signUp status code : \(statusCode)")

                guard (200...299).contains(statusCode) else {
                    return
                }

                self.logger.debug("UserId: \(userId)")
            })
            .store(in: &disposables)
```

And my publisher here

```
static func postAccount(
        withSignUpCommand signUpCommand: SignUpCommand,
        apiResponseQueue: DispatchQueue = CloudHospitalClientAPI.apiResponseQueue
    ) -> AnyPublisher<(Int, String), Error> {
        let url = "\(CloudHospitalClientAPI.identityBasePath)/api/v1/accounts"

        let parameters = JSONEncodingHelper.encodingParameters(forEncodableObject: signUpCommand)

        return Future<(Int, String), Error>.init { promise in
            postAccountWithRequestBuilder(withURLString: url, withParameters: parameters, isBody: true).execute(apiResponseQueue) { result -> Void in
                switch result {
                    case let .success(response):
                        promise(.success((response.statusCode, response.body!)))
                    case let .failure(error):
                        promise(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    }

    static func postAccountWithRequestBuilder(
        withURLString URLString: String,
        withParameters parameters: [String: Any]?,
        isBody: Bool
    ) -> RequestBuilder<String> {

        let url = URLComponents(string: URLString)
        let requestBuilder: RequestBuilder<String>.Type = CloudHospitalClientAPI.requestBuilderFactory.getBuilder()

        return requestBuilder.init(method: "POST", URLString: (url?.string ?? URLString), parameters: parameters, isBody: isBody)
    }
```

When debugging this, I get below result.
[image: Debugging]

The api error response below format and I'd like to parse this Data but can't access to this value at all.
[image: Error response from api(swagger)]

Tried to change the Return type to custom error response but had no luck.

Please share some advice where I can insert decoding error response code and return to caller function.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks to Bruno, below is my edited code.

```
        AccountAPI.postAccount(withSignUpCommand: signUpCommand)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] result in
                guard let self = self else { return }

                switch result {
                    case .finished:
                        self.logger.debug("signUp completed.")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self.isAuthenticating = false
                        self.logger.error("signUp error : \(error)")
                        if case let ErrorResponse.error(_, data, _) = error {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            let identityErrors = try! decoder.decode([IdentityError].self, from: data!)

                            // TODO: Decode `data` here...
                            self.logger.debug("data: \(String(describing: identityErrors))")

                            self.errors = identityErrors
                        }
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] (statusCode, userId) in
                guard let self = self else { return }

                self.logger.debug("signUp status code : \(statusCode)")

                guard (200...299).contains(statusCode) else {
                    return
                }

                self.logger.debug("UserId: \(userId)")
            })
            .store(in: &disposables)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check if this solves your problem?

```
AccountAPI.postAccount(withSignUpCommand: signUpCommand)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            switch result {
                case .finished:
                    self.logger.debug("signUp completed.")
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.isAuthenticating = false
                    self.logger.error("signUp error : \(error)")

                    if case let ErrorResponse.error(statusCode, data, error) = error {

                        // TODO: Decode `data` here...
                        
                    }
            }
        }, receiveValue: { [weak self] (statusCode, userId) in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            self.logger.debug("signUp status code : \(statusCode)")
        })
        .store(in: &disposables)
```